# How to handle array of objects in node.js using express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have 2 collection,

```
var Sub= new Schema({
    content: String,
    date: Date
});

var Main= new Schema({
    subs: [Sub]
});
```

I am creating and deleting this way:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    new Sub({
        content: req.body.content
    }).save(function(err, sub) {
        Main.update({_id: req.body.mid}, {$push: {subs: sub}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, mmain) {
            res.redirect('/' + req.body.mid);
        });
    });
};
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
    Sub.findOne({_id: req.params.sid}, function(err, sub) {
        Main.update({_id: req.params.mid}, {$pull: {subs: sub}}, function(err, mmain) {
            sub.remove(function(err, sub) {
                res.redirect('/' + req.params.mid);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

So basically I'm first creating a sub object, and then I use .update to $push that sub object into the main collection. However, when I delete one sub object from the list, I also have to delete the original sub object. Is there another way to do it? So I only have to change one sub object instead of having to change both the sub that now sits inside the Main object and also the original sub object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out how to do it. It rather suited my app to use embedded sub than to have another Schema and collection so I deleted the Sub collection and edited the Main collection to:

```
var Main= new Schema({
          subs: [
                 content: String,
                 date: Date
                ] 
          });


exports.create = function(req, res) {
    Main.update({_id: req.body.mid}, {$push: {subs: {content: req.body.content}}}, {upsert: true},function(err, main) {
        res.end();
    });
};
```